# How to calculate price given payback period?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a capex table to calculate investment of a new product.

As shown in pic[image]  all numbers are not real numbers

**D83** is the initial investment, meaning we invest $15,800 to buy machine and space

**E85** to **I85** are the variable cost each year.

**E86** to **I86** are the revenue each year, `revenue = price * est.sold quantity`

`E87=E85+E86`, `F87=F85+F86`, etc.

`D91 = {INDEX($E$87:$I$87,MATCH(TRUE,$E$89:$I$89>0,0))}`  This is an array to find the first positive cash flow of Row 89 and return the value in row 87

`D92 = {INDEX($E$83:$I$83,MATCH(TRUE,$E$89:$I$89>0,0))}`  This is an array to find the first positive cash flow of Row 89 and return the value in row 83

```
D93 = COUNTIF(E89:I89,"<0")+((-D92)/D91)
```

In this way, I calculated the payback years of a project.

In cell **D98** I need to calculate that given a certain payback year number, other things hold still, what the price needs to be. Since **D91** and **D92** are arrays to lookup for the first positive cash flow and each year cash flow is not even, I can't think of a formula to put in **D98** so **D98** changes with **C98**, for example, if I put `2` in **C98** meaning I need the payback period to be 2 years, and **D98** will automatically give me a number to show what price it should be.

Is there any formula or VBA to do it?